Idempotent suplattice endomorphisms which commute
Let $X$ be a suplattice and let $f, g$ be suplattice endomorphisms of $X$. Suppose $$f \circ f = f$$
$$g \circ g = g$$
$$f \circ g = g \circ f$$
What can we say about $f, g$?

For $X$ the powerset of some set $S$ these correspond to transitive dense (for any $a,b\in S$ with $aRb$ there exists $c\in S$ with $aRc$ and $cRb$) relations on $S$ which commute (for any $aRbR'c$ there exists $d$ with $aR'dRc$). These have been studied under various names, such as "information system" or "infosys" for example.

Oh, that is what inspired this question. I didn't know the term infosys, and I was worried if I phrased this in relation terms it would be more esoteric. I guess I was wrong, oops. Still, might as well leave up the question as-is I suppose. EDIT: I cannot find any mention of an "infosys" on Google. Can you specify where they're used? I just thought it was interesting that because they're cosemigroups in Rel, they can specify a semigroup structure on power sets. (And then I noticed this construction can be extended to any suplattice.)

I had in mind e. g. the approach from this paper, see also references there. But I am pretty sure there are entirely different approaches under entirely different names
